# $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x)(1+x^{3})\cdots(1+x^{2n+1}),|x|<1.$

Tags: calculus, limits

I‘d like to find the limit .
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x)(1+x^{3})\cdots(1+x^{2n+1}),|x|<1$$
But I have no way to simplify the formula.If the powers are even,it will be easy to simplify it.Any help will be thanked.